# How to use if else statement to throw error if a value in dataframe column is NULL?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I'm reading a csv file as a DF in which last 3 mandatory columns hold NULL values [csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7Ax1.jpg)

Can anyone please guide me on how to use an if else statement within a UDF in scala spark in such a way that if there are any null values in those columns it should throw an error stating "Mandatory fields cannot be null" ? I have written the code in scala spark so it'll be helpful if I get any suggestions in it.

This is my first code so please forgive my mistakes. From the below code please guide me on how to fetch the details in such a way that if any of the IF condition did not satisfy, the job should fail and logs will be captured with the error message given in ELSE statement, if the conditions satisfy the resultant DF should be inserted into the database. Please share your suggestions :

```
import java.util.Date
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


object InputValidation {

  val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("Excel to DataFrame")
    .setMaster("local[*]")

  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Excel to DataFrame")
    .config("spark.master", "local")
    .getOrCreate()




 val structType: StructType = {
    val sno = StructField("S.No", IntegerType, nullable = true)
    val fname = StructField("Firm Name", StringType, nullable = true)
    val address = StructField("Address", StringType, nullable = true)
    val country = StructField("Country", StringType, nullable = true)
    val pcode = StructField("Post Code", IntegerType, nullable = true)
    val tnumber = StructField("Telephone Number", IntegerType, nullable = true)
    val waddress = StructField("Web Address", StringType, nullable = true)
    val mail = StructField("Mail ID", StringType, nullable = true)
    val fstatus = StructField("Firm Status", StringType, nullable = false)
    val btype = StructField("Business Type", StringType, nullable = false)
    val edate = StructField("Effective Date", DateType, nullable = false)
    new StructType(Array(sno, fname, address, country, pcode, tnumber, waddress, mail,
      fstatus, btype, edate))
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val inputDF: DataFrame = spark.read
      .schema(structType)
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("delimiter", ",")
      .csv("G:\\CSV\\FirmRegistration.csv")


def isValidUDF: Object = udf({
  (fstatus: String, btype: String, edate: Date) => {
    val validfs = Seq("New", "Authorised", "EEA Authorised", "Cancelled")
    if (validfs.contains(fstatus)) {
      return fstatus
    }
    else {
      throw new Exception("Incorrect firm status")
    }

    val validbt = Seq("Regulated", "PSD", "EEA")
    if (validbt.contains(btype)) {
      return btype
    }
    else {
      throw new Exception("Incorrect firm business type")
    }

    if (edate != null) {
      return edate
    }
    else {
      throw new Exception("Effective date cannot be NULL")
    }
  }
})

  val userDF = udf(isValidUDF _)
  val resultDF = inputDF.withColumn("IsValid", userDF())
  resultDF.show()

//Load the result as a table into Database
    val driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    val url = "jdbc:postgressql://localhost:5432/rtjvm"
    val user = "docker"
    val password = "docker"

    inputDF.write
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("driver",driver)
      .option("url",url)
      .option("user",user)
      .option("password",password)
      .option("dbtable","public.input")
      .save()
```

}

}

If I run the above program, I am getting the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Object is not supported

Comment: `if not df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].notna().all(): # raise exception`

Comment: Although better still, your database should have the necessary constraints to ensure erroneous data is not inserted.

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkNullUDF = udf({
  (firmStatus: String, businessType: String, effectiveDate: String) => {
    if(firmStatus == null || businessType == null || effectiveDate == null) true else false
  }
})

df.withColumn("IsNull", checkNullUDF($"Firm Status", $"Business Type", $"Effective Date")
```

This will give you a column "IsNull" with true/false values which you can use to throw an exception accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, ashishyadav. I have added my code in this post now. Can you please advise how the requested condition can be achieved in that code ?

Comment: Are you sure your if conditions are correct? Instead of "fstatus.contains(validfs)", shouldn't it be "validfs.contains(fstatus)" and same with the next if condition. Anyways, if you just want your code to fail in else block, you can throw an exception there. Something like this: 

if (validfs.contains(fstatus)) {
      return fstatus
    }
    else {
      throw new Exception("Incorrect firm status")
    }

Comment: Thanks again, Ashish. Just noticed that I have misplaced the args in IF condition. Now I have added exception. I made corrections and ran the code but I'm getting error as "isValidUDF does not take parameters" in the line inputDF.withColumn("IsValid", isValidUDF($"Firm Status", $"Business Type",$ "Effective Date"))

Comment: Hi all, please share if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: Hi Shyam, don't register as a udf again because you have already registered isValidUDF as a udf while defining it on top. 

Remove these lines of code

val userDF = udf(isValidUDF _)
val resultDF = inputDF.withColumn("IsValid", userDF())

And instead just use:

inputDF.withColumn("IsValid", isValidUDF($"Firm Status", $"Business Type",$ "Effective Date"))

Comment: Thanks, Ashish. But if I use that, I'm getting an error as "isValidUDF does not take parameters". I think I've made mistake in declaring return type for isValidUDF function. Can you please confirm whether Object is an apt return type for isValidUDF ?